# Proof by induction: not sure where I'm going wrong.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Using mathematical induction, prove that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (i(i!)) = (n+1)! - 1,
$$

for all positive integers n.

I proved the base case where i=1, so I moved on to assuming that

$$
\sum_{i=1}^k (i(i!)) = (k+1)! - 1,
$$

is true.

Then, I continued to

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (i(i!)) = ((k+1)+1)! - 1,
$$

$$
\sum_{i=1}^k (i(i!)) + (k+1((k+1)!))
$$

$$
((k+1)!-1) + (k+1((k+1)!))
$$

$$
2(k+1)!+k-1
$$

I think I am doing this wrong; I don't know how to go from what I found to 
$$
(k+1)+1)! - 1
$$

Comment: $$i\cdot i! = ((i+1)-1)\cdot i! = (i+1)!-i!.$$

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have a mistake with the parenthesis. In the second row of the inductive step you have $(k+1)(k+1)!$ not $k + 1(k+1)!$. That would mean that you will end up with $(k+1 + 1)(k+1)! - 1 = (k+2)(k+1)! - 1 = (k+2)! - 1$

Comment: I can't believe it was as simple as a parenthesis mistake. This clears it up, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (i(i!)) = \sum_{i=1}^k (i(i!)) +(k+1)(k+1)!
$$
I think you should be able to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

1) n = 1 $\Rightarrow S_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{1}=(1+1)!-1=1$

2) n --> n+1 $\Rightarrow S_{n+1} =\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i\,i!= \sum_{i=1}^{n}i\,i!+ (n+1)(n+1)!=(n+1)!-1+ (n+1)(n+1)!=$

$=(n+1)!(1+n+1)-1=(n+2)(n+1)!-1=(n+2)!-1$

Q.E.D.